# PHP get single file name from directory

Tags: php, image, glob

trying to get a single file from directory (alphabetically)

and the file types would be png jpeg tiff gif

final out put would be  like
echo firstimage.jpg  nextiamge.jpg previous.img

cant get it work .. 
started withi this

this one i recovered from power amendments where not saved (showing work)

```
function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); 
$num = array_rand($ar); 
return $ar[$num];
}

function getImagesFromDir($path) {
$images = array();
if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
// checks for gif, jpg, png
if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
$images[] = $img_file; 
}
}
closedir($img_dir); 
}
return $images; 
echo $images;
}

$root = '/ers/m'; 
// If images not in sub directory of current directory specify root 
//$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$path = ''; 

// Obtain list of images from directory 
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);

$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
```

what im trying to make is a slide show ... from directory
but i can now output the first file..

but thats it 
    echo "slideshow.php?nextimage.jpg"

here is basic idea
$dir = '*.jpg, *.png'; etc
getfirst name from directory
getnext name from directory

thanks to Rizier123 
        $types = array("png", "jpeg", "tiff", "gif");
        $files = array();

```
    foreach($types as $type) {
        $files[$type] = glob("*.$type");
    }

    array_multisort($files);

    foreach($files as $key => $type) {
        if(count($type) > 0) {
            echo "Type: " . $key . " First file: " . $type[0];
        }
    }
```

sorry not fair being voted down i tried to save the work but we have horrible power in my country

Comment: all the code i tried to paste didnt work  and we had power out ...

Comment: @fromVBbasic98toPHP You have to show your work and what you have tried! Otherwise it just looks like we do your work and you get payed for it! So that's maybe why you get down Votes

Comment: Rizier Exactly correct but we had power out i started from sctach if you see other posts (with my work) sitll no replioes) sorry man

Comment: sorry how do i do that? i am still learning ..     im trying to make a php image slide show thanks to you i got the first image but cant go next

Comment: i figired out how to "accept answer"

Comment: @fromVBbasic98toPHP Maybe you want to look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: if i send you 10 dollars could you help me with CURL logging to website ? i have all teh work done just getting "page time out"

Comment: @fromVBbasic98toPHP http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $types = array("png", "jpeg", "tiff", "gif");
    $files = array();

    foreach($types as $type) {
        $files[$type] = glob("*.$type");
    }

    array_multisort($files);

    foreach($files as $key => $type) {
        if(count($type) > 0) {
            echo "Type: " . $key . " First file: " . $type[0];
        }
    }

?>
```

possible Output:

```
Type: png First file: gre.png
Type: gif First file: 1.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

this one i recovered from power amendments where not saved (showing work)

```
function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); 
$num = array_rand($ar); 
return $ar[$num];
}

function getImagesFromDir($path) {
$images = array();
if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
// checks for gif, jpg, png
if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
$images[] = $img_file; 
}
}
closedir($img_dir); 
}
return $images; 
echo $images;
}

$root = '/ers/m'; 
// If images not in sub directory of current directory specify root 
//$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$path = ''; 

// Obtain list of images from directory 
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);

$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
```

Comment: You can add this to your question and show what you have done! (Edit button under question)